# Can't find USB flash drive in terminal in VirtualBox guest

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu on a VirtualBox with the purpose of building an LFS. 
At first I had trouble getting my flash drive to be detected, It wouldn't show up on my disks. But I fixed the issue. 
Now, when I try to access my flash drive from the terminal it says the drive doesn't exist. I can see it clearly on my drives under `/dev/sdb`, but my terminal is saying it cant detect that drive. 
The flash drive is completely empty. And I'm running my VirtualBox on Windows 10.

Comment: can you please post the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you paste the commands and their outputs of your actions?

Comment: cfdisk /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Virtualbox to share that specific usb device.

To make sure Ubuntu sees it, run `lsusb` with it attached and unattached. If it displays in that listing it is at least seeing it, and it *should* display the drive in Files.

Comment: Okay, it IS displaying it in lsusb. And it's still showing up in my Disks. But when I try cfdisk /dev/sdb it states "cannot open disk drive."

Comment: @SmilodonFatalis Are you certain it's /dev/sdb? And what does cfdisk do that the Ubuntu disk manager doesn't?